# Why are vectors and one-forms treated as equal in Euclidean space?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I know that in general a vector space $V$ and its dual space $V^{\ast}$ are distinct from one another, and that given a metric $g$ an isomorphism between the two can be constructed, defined by $V^{\mu}=g^{\mu\nu}\omega_{\nu}$, where $V=V^{\mu}e_{\mu}\in V$ and $\omega =\omega_{\mu}dx^{\mu}\in V^{\ast}$. As I understand ( I may be incorrect), one can use quantities other than the metric to construct such an isomorphism between the two spaces and hence $V$ and $V^{\ast}$ aren't *naturally* isomorphic, in general.

However, in (slightly more) elementary linear algebra, when considering Euclidean (flat) space, endowed with the standard Euclidean metric, we treat vectors and one-forms as if they are the same object - one does not distinguish between the two. Why is it possible to do this? Is it simply that in this case there is a natural isomorphism between the two (given via the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$), or is there something else to it?

Comment: They are different vector spaces and the way that vectors and covectors are related is thru the Riesz' Representation Thm.

Comment: In elementary linear algebra, they often _are_ distinguished: elements of $V$ are called "column vectors" and elements of $V^*$ are called "row vectors".

Comment: @EricWofsey    Sorry, I missed out a vital detail - I meant specifically in Euclidean (flat) space, with the Euclidean metric defined (have updated my question to clarify that point).

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that a choice of nondegenerate bilinear form $g$ on a vector space $V$ induces an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$. (Fun fact: This is often called a "musical isomorphism" because in Einstein notation, the effect is to raise/lower, i.e., sharpen/flatten, indices.)

A choice of *basis* $e_i$ for $V$ also induces an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ by mapping the basis to its dual basis, $e_i\mapsto e^i$, and then extending to all of $V$ by linearity.

The canonical basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$ gives an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$. The inner product also gives an isomorphism. In the case of Euclidean space, the two isomorphisms coincide on every tangent space (that is, the canonical basis is orthornormal with respect to the inner product). Teachers often do not make this distinction in elementary linear algebra classes. I would speculate this is for two reasons: One, it's a subtle point that may be lost on students without enough mathematical maturity; two, elementary linear algebra often focuses on matrix algebra computations instead of the structure of vector spaces.

Also, as Eric Wofsey points out, sometimes teachers do make a distinction by identifying one-forms with row vectors and vectors with column vectors. The musical isomorphisms are then given by transposition. I believe this is the case in Hubbard-Hubbard's book on linear algebra and multivariable calculus.

---

Beware conflating "equal" and "naturally isomorphic"! The two are not the same set or objects. There is an identification between them and they have the same properties. Think of different types of identifications as classification. In the same way, when speaking precisely, we don't say all mammals are equal, or the same, even though they have the same characteristic "mammalness" properties.

Comment: So is it simply that in Euclidean space the isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{\ast}$ is *natural*, i.e. it doesn't depend on an arbitrary choice, and so the elements of the two spaces can be considered equal (in much the same way as a vector space and its double dual are naturally isomorphic and as such the elements of $V$ and $V^{\ast\ast}$ can be considered as equal)?

Comment: @Will I have edited and expanded the answer. Here's a couple of additional points. First, beware conflating "equal" and "naturally isomorphic"! The two are *not* the same set, there is just a natural identification between them. Second, you're correct, the isomorphism between $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $(\Bbb{R}^n)^*$ depends not on an arbitrary choice, but on a choice made when setting up the theory (in this case, the basis given to $\Bbb{R}^n$ as a product vector space).

Comment: Sorry, yes I realise they are not actually equal, I technically should have written that they are *equivalent*, but I was looking for a slightly stronger statement than equivalent as an isomorphism in general is an equivalence relation, right? ....

Comment: ... However, in non-Euclidean spaces, where we construct an isomorphism between a tangent space and its corresponding dual space via the metric, we certainly distinguish between the two (I'm highlighting this point as when I was taught elementary linear algebra, in which to start we only dealt with vectors, the lecturer mentioned dual vectors, but then proceeded to say that in Euclidean space there is no distinction between dual vectors and vectors and so we need only consider vectors).

Comment: The reason you want to distinguish vectors and dual vectors even when you have a metric (which canonically identifies them) is that you want to consider linear maps which don't preserve the metric.  So, the isomorphism you have is _not_ natural with respect to all the maps you care about; it's only natural with respect to isometries.  In the language of elementary linear algebra, this is just the fact that matrices act differently on column vectors than they do on row vectors.